# Rails ActiveRecord scopes with multiple joins and has_one associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scope, rails-activerecord, rails-models

I’m creating some scopes inside of my `Job` model, which will be used by ActiveAdmin to filter out jobs at various stages of the pipeline.

I’m having to create joins to other tables to gather the relevant info, and this is where I’m running into trouble. I’ve outline my logic and (non-working) attempts below.

How would I refactor these so that they work properly?

```
# app/models/job.rb

# where job.survey exists AND job.appointment.appointment_date is in past AND job.quote doesn’t exist

scope :awaiting_quote, -> { joins(:survey).
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN quotes ON quote.job_id = jobs.id').
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN appointments ON appointment.job_id = jobs.id').
  where('appointment.appointment_date < :current_time', { current_time: Time.current }).
  where('survey.id IS NOT NULL').
  where('quote.id IS NULL')
}

# where job.quote exists AND job.quote_accepted is false

scope :awaiting_acceptance, -> { joins(:quote).
  joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN appointments ON quote.job_id = jobs.id').
  where('appointment.appointment_date < :current_time', { current_time: Time.current }).
  where('quote.id IS NOT NULL').
  where('quote_accepted = :quote_accepted', { quote_accepted: false })
}

has_one :quote
has_one :survey
has_one :appointment
has_one :surveyor, through: :appointment
accepts_nested_attributes_for :appointment, :allow_destroy => true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :survey, :allow_destroy => true

# app/models/quote.rb

belongs_to :job

# app/models/survey.rb

belongs_to :job

# app/models/appointment.rb

belongs_to :job
belongs_to :surveyor

# app/models/surveyor.rb

has_many :appointments
has_many :jobs, through: :appointments
```

Comment: Can you post your model code? This doesn't seem overly complex given a sound model/association design.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question with my model code.

Comment: Have you thought about using class methods instead?

Comment: Those where clauses are using singularized model names, but the tables are pluralized. When you pass a string to `where` it is assumed to be a SQL fragment.

Comment: I’m still very stuck on this. How would I go about editing my answer to get the scope working?

Answer (score 1):

As there are no conflicts in the column names between tables, the trick is to join all the tables, and just perform `where` methods on the combined data.

```
scope :awaiting_quote, -> {
  joins(:survey, :quote, :appointment).
  where('quote IS NULL').
  where('appointment_date < :current_time', current_time: Time.current)
}

scope :awaiting_acceptance, -> {
  joins(:quote, :appointment).
  where('appointment_date < :current_time', current_time: Time.current).
  where('quote IS NOT NULL').
  where('quote_accepted = :quote_accepted', quote_accepted: false)
}
```